# Cannot use variables in StreamWriter filename

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile

I am getting an error in my Windows Mobile app when writing to a text file. I am first creating a filename:

```
filename = "IncomingUnit_" + GlobalVar.getDate() + ".txt";
```

This prints out correctly to the console as 'IncomingUnit_2017053111:22:57.txt'.

Then I'm writing lines to that file using a StreamWriter.

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true))
{
    foreach (Record _record in records)
    {
        writer.Write(_record);
    }
}
```

This gives me a exception and the file is not created:
'A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll'

If I take out the GlobalVar.GetDate it creates the file and writes the data.

```
filename = "IncomingUnit.txt";
```

How can I insert the date into my filename?

Comment: If you want date use tostring ("yyyyMMddHHmmss") to create the filename

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Colon **":"** character in the filename is invalid.

Just replace it to a valid character before using it in StreamWriter:

```
filename = filename.Replace(":", "_");
```

[According to MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/905231/information-about-the-characters-that-you-cannot-use-in-site-names,-folder-names,-and-file-names-in-sharepoint), you can not use the following characters in filenames:

```
Tilde (~)
Number sign (#)
Percent (%)
Ampersand (&)
Asterisk (*)
Braces ({ })
Backslash (\)
Colon (:)
Angle brackets (< >)
Question mark (?)
Slash (/)
Plus sign (+)
Pipe (|)
Quotation mark (")
```

Comment: Yep that solved it. Is there any way to use the colon character, or do I need to use an alternative character like a dash? (IncomingUnit_2017053111-22-57.txt)

Comment: @DaleTownsend No, there is no way to use colon. You need to use alternative character.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the filename "IncomingUnit_2017053111:22:57.txt" you used, the special character like ':" cannot be used for creating filename

Comment: Here's the full list of reserved characters in Windows filenames: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#file_and_directory_names

Comment: yes, exactly, that's why the file is not created, because the filename consist reserved characters used by windows

Answer (score 1):

Below  characters are not allowed in a file name.
You cannot use the following characters anywhere in a file name:

- Tilde.
- Number sign.
- Percent.
- Ampersand.
- Asterisk.
- Braces.
- Backslash.
- Colon.